# ASP.NET Core Middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, middleware

I have build custom Identity Middle-ware. Inside Invoke method I am checking if request has token etc. After token is checked I want to pass request further to controller. It`s working for GET request - it jump into controller method. It is not working for POST request.

Here is Invoke Method

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    //checking
    await _next(context);
}
```

Its working controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    // GET api/values
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    public string Get()
    {
        return "Allow annymous";
    }
 }
```

And not working one

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public void Login()
    {
         //some logic
          HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync("Unauthorized");
    }
}
```

> Making POST call Postman returns 404 not found.

Comment: You are surely making POST request to /api/Account?

Comment: Is there any other POST methods in thecsame controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The route for the action in question would be `/api/Account`. Make sure that is correct.

If instead you wanted `/api/Account/Login`:

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public void Login()
    {
         //some logic
          HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync("Unauthorized");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try returning something like an `IActionResult` rather than simply void.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Login() 
{
    // some logic
    return Unauthorized();
}
```

Comment: Can you try removing `[AllowAnonymous]` and see if same issue exists? Also try adding a specific route at the class level like `[Route("api/foo")]` and hitting the `POST` against "api/foo" and see if you get response.

Comment: How are you executing the POST exactly? What does the URL look like?  Are you adding any header values or do you have anything in `startup.cs` what would prevent POST from happening like authentication restrictions?

Comment: I am doing it on default ctonroller values and doing this by postman now without any middleware or anything like that and it return 500 and the point is i can check what is really error

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code I hopping there is only one method inside the `AccountController` called `Login`. If not please add attribute `[Route("Login")]` to `Login` method (make sure you do not keep it empty like `[Route("Login")]` otherwise it will have same as what you are doing currently).

Then make the call to the `POST http://host:***/api/account/login` url and that should work.

FYI: I have tried this thing on my machine and it is working.